# For appending another field value (here id) in the end of password in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

For appending another field value (here id) in the end of password in MySQL,In my table usermaster,

```
+----+-------------+  
| id | password    |  
+----+-------------+  
|  1 | anju        |  
|  2 | lija        |  
|  3 | bhumi       |  
|  4 | henry       |  
+----+-------------+
```

i need my updated table like this below

```
+----+-------------+  
| id | password    |  
+----+-------------+  
|  1 | anju@1      |  
|  2 | lija@2      |  
|  3 | bhumi@3     |  
|  4 | henry@4     |  
+----+-------------+
```

By appending password field with "id" in end along with "@". My query is like this:

```
UPDATE `user_master` SET `password` = concat(password,id)  WHERE 1
```

But it appends only id, how can i do "@" also. Please some one help me

Comment: Typically, you wouldn't store data that can be so easily 'calculated ' on-the-fly

Comment: you should use `concat(password,'@',id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as

```
UPDATE `user_master` SET `password`=concat(password,'@',id)
```

Check the document here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) function:

```sql
UPDATE `user_master`
SET `password` = CONCAT_WS('@', password, id)
```